# How to add accents or special characters in sender profile from name

Tags: marketing-cloud, character-encoding

Does anyone have any experience using accented letters in the from name in a sender profile, for example, a French name with an accented e. I've tried inserting the ASCII character code in the sender profile field, but it doesn't take it.
Thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. It works for me. What browser are you using?